# People Picker suffixes user name with "Active Directory" in SharePoint on Prem, "Tenanat" in SharePoint online when Check Names is clicked

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, people-picker

We are facing an issue when we resolve people picker using the "Check Names" icon.

In **SharePoint 2013:** it shows the screen below:

When I type a user name (not login id) in the people picker text box, if that user is not resolved automatically, when I go to click over "Check Names" ico, it suggests me matching user name suffixing [Active Directory], for example Ankur Pial [Active Directory]. When I select the name from auto suggest list, it puts the name **Ankur Pial [Active Directory]**.

That's annoying. In the below screen I have shown that.

[image]

**SharePoint Online**: Almost same thing happens, but it shows [Tenant] as a suffix. Something like this:

[image]

I want to know why this happens and how I can get rid of this? I don't want to show my end users [Active Directory] or [Tenant] thing, they don't understand these!

Advance help is appreciated!

Comment: This looks like SharePoint 2010 PeoplePicker. Where do you use it? A Form? Do you experience the same issue on a Site with SharePoint 2013 PeoplePicker?

Comment: Yes it's a custom new form for list. The first scenario is for SharePoint 2013, the second one is SharePoint online.

Comment: Do you experience the same issue on a Site with SharePoint 2013 PeoplePicker?

Comment: Yes, for SharePoint 2013 it shows [Active Directory] suffixes with User Name.